# Limit inside WhereHas

Tags: php, laravel

So I want to get requests which have last status equal to given status
I've tried with first() but it gives me an error and limit is not working

```
$requests = Request::whereHas('requestStatus', function ($query) use ($status) {
            return $query->where('status',$status)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
        })->get();
```

**Controller**

```
    public function listByStatus($status)
    {   

        $requests = Request::whereHas('requestStatus', function ($query) use ($status) {
        return $query->where('status',$status)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
    })->get();


        return view('admin.request.list',compact('requests','status'));
    }
```

**Model Request**

```
public function requestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RequestStatus');
}
```

**Migration RequestStatus**

```
Schema::create('request_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('request_id')->unsigned();;
    $table->foreign('request_id')->references('id')->on('requests');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: what is the relationship between the Request and RequestStatus, 1 to 1 I guess?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin one to many

Comment: And there is a reference to Request in RequestStatus, I mean like `request_id`?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin of course I'll update the question with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$requests = Request::select('requests.*')
    ->join('request_status', 'requests.id', 'request_status.request_id')
    ->where('request_status.status', $status)
    ->where('request_status.id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('request_status')
            ->whereColumn('request_id', 'requests.id')
            ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
            ->limit(1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid N+1 problem you can use the power of the collections :

```
$requests = Request::whereHas('requestStatus', function ($query) use ($status) {
            return $query->where('status',$status)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
        })->get()
          ->map(function($request) {
                $request->setRelation('requestStatus', $request->requestStatus->take(1));
                return $request;
            });
```

Comment: thank you very much but it still not working like expected, so what I want to achieve I have a lisitng of request by current status and using your solution it still showing the same request in diffrent lisitng: eg: one request have pending then accepted status I want that it appear only by last status

Answer (score 1):

You can make things simple by making two separate queries:

1. Query where there is `status = 'your status'`. Something like,

   ```
   $request_status_ids = RequestStatus::where('status', '=', $status)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->limit(1)->pluck('request_id');
   ```
2. Then Query from `Request` where the RequestId matches.

   ```
   Request::whereIn('id', $request_status_ids->all())->get();
   ```

Practically, the result should return one value record anyway, but I left `get()` so that it may *look like* the query you have.

After you've understood how to use `whereAs()` if you need it you can then do the same. But right now, this should help you find the needed result at first then you can improve later on.

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help you with this:

```
$requests = Request::with(['requestStatus' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
}])->whereHas('requestStatus', function ($query) use ($status) {
    return $query->where('status',$status);
})->get();
```