# how to limit the number of data in where has query laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query like so

```php
$data = City::with('hotel')->orwherehas('hotel', function ($query) use ($user_input) {
    //here i want to limit this result to 5
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $user_input . '%')->take(5);
    //                $query->take(5); i have tried this too

})->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $user_input . '%')->get();
```

inside the `whereHas` clause, I have a query that I want to limit to 5, now I tried `limit`, `take` but no luck after that `where` nothing is working I don't know why

Comment: I think you spelled it incorrectly, it's [orWhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit inside WhereHas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271514/limit-inside-wherehas)

Comment: @KoalaYeung i dont want to use joins if possible

Comment: To be clear, do you want to limit the cities WHICH HAVE 5 or less hotels with an inputted name? Or are you trying to only return a maximum of 5 hotels with the city which have the inputted hotel name?

Comment: its a search i want to bring all cities and hotels than contain name `la` for example but because the number of hotels are so much i want to limit the hotels to some cap

Comment: @thisiskelvin now it wont bring the hotel it self as i tried

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your query to the `->with()` query builder method:

```
$data = City::with(['hotel' => function($query) use ($user_input) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $user_input . '%')->limit(5);
}])
->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $user_input . '%')
->get();
```

This will get all hotels associated with a city which have the user input, where the city contains the user input.

Note that the `->orWhere()` is not used here.

Comment: Just one more thing is that if a user searches for `hotel palace` if the city does not exist which will not exist it should returns the hotel it self . i wont get problem with it ??

Comment: You are right, with this you need to identify if this functionality should be searching for the hotel or searching for a city.

Comment: Doing both will require a different query altogether, maybe a condition between 2 queries to check if there is a city with a hotel with the user input, if not, search for a city with the user input, and fail if none found. Do you want me to add to this answer?